# Configuring Figma version 3.0.07 to Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, documentation, configure, figma

I couldnt configure Figma 3.0.07 to Android Studio. I change libraries and sometimes it gaved me Duplicate class exception also missing class exception I couldnt find useful documentation about that.
Also I tried to configure it with Relay For Figma. But if is there any other ways to make my project designed better you can help me and give information about that

Hello everyone have a good day. Today, I wanted to change my android studio projects design and I wanna configure Figma to my project. I read the documentation and do whatever they want but firstly The compiler gave me exception. Then , tried different ways to configure it. I change depencies version etc. But I couldnt find real depencies. Also, I couldnt find figma's last documentation that shows us depencies and other thing either Android Studio. Do you guys know how to configure it. Could you gave me build. grandle and settings.grandle files. (Also version isnt important)